# why lookbehind assertion regex not working if any character previously it

Tags: javascript, regex

My problem is that I need to put another text before the lookbehind

This does not work or is not valid => /one (?<=tow) there/.test("one tow there")

But this is works and is valid => /(?<=tow) there/.test("tow there")

Comment: Why do you need lookarounds at all here?

Comment: i need match this /http(s)?:\/\/((?<=w{3})\.)\w+/ to valid those 
"(https://www.google.com)" or "https:/google.com

Comment: Okay, but what purpose is the lookaround supposed to serve there? Why can't you directly write out the pattern without any lookarounds?

Comment: That lookbehind `one (?<=tow)` will never work because you have only matched `one ` so there can neven be tow to the left. Why not like `https?:\/\/www\.\S+` or `https?:\/\/\S+\.[a-z]{2,}`

Comment: The difference is that www. before the name and can be without it, but must end with a domain

Comment: www. is optional

Comment: "https://www.googlecom".match(/https?:\/\/\S+\.[a-z]{2,}/)
This is not valid, but the match method is telling that it is valid
I need to differentiate between the dot relation after the www and the another dot  before the domain

Comment: @moazabdelrazek Can you update the question with examples of what should and what should not match so volunteers have a clear scenario to test.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the solution I managed to make**

```js
const regx = /https?:\/\/(?=(w{3}\.[a-z]+\.[a-z]{2,}|(?<!https?:\/\/(?=w{3}\.))[a-z]+\.[a-z]{2,}))/;

console.log(regx.test("http://www.google.com"))
console.log(regx.test("http://google.com"))
```